# google maps infowindow.close() case in separate function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to make infowindow-making process in the different function, cause it`s gonna contains much info.

I have a global-defined var `infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});`

when i`m trying to close it in the separate function, infowindow.close() method doesn`t works.
Can`t get, wat is wrong here? the infowindow object is successfully passed into the function, cause new infowindows creating successfully

Here is a full code

```js
var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var markers = [];

///////////
///markers initialization
///////////
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.923036, 151.259052);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: myLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);


    var num_markers = locations.length;

    //set infowindow global to prevent multiply opening
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++) {
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat:locations[i][1], lng:locations[i][2]},
            map: map,
            id: locations[i][3]
        });

        //here is a special stuff to pass iterator
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', (function(i,infowindow, map) {
            return function() {
                MakeContent(i,infowindow, map);
            }
        })(i,infowindow, map));

    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


function MakeContent(i,infowindow, map){

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>Uluru Hop</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
        'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
        'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
        'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
        '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
        'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
        'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
        'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
        'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
        'Heritage Site.</p>'+
        '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
        '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

        infowindow.close();
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
           id: markers[i].id,
           content:contentString,
           position:new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1],locations[i][2])
        });
        infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infowindow is local to the initialize function. Make it global (define it outside of any function).  Probably simpler to reuse the existing infowindow than recreate it.

[proof of concept jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/k31y66vr/1/)

```js
var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var markers = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
///////////
///markers initialization
///////////
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.923036, 151.259052);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: myLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);


    var num_markers = locations.length;

    //set infowindow global to prevent multiply opening
    
    for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++) {
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat:locations[i][1], lng:locations[i][2]},
            map: map,
            id: locations[i][3]
        });

        //here is a special stuff to pass iterator
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', (function(i,infowindow, map) {
            return function() {
                MakeContent(i, map);
            }
        })(i,infowindow, map));

    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


function MakeContent(i, map){

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>Uluru Hop</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
        'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
        'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
        'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
        '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
        'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
        'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
        'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
        'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
        'Heritage Site.</p>'+
        '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
        '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

        infowindow.close();
        infowindow.setMap(null);
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
           id: markers[i].id,
           content:contentString,
           position:new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1],locations[i][2])
        });
        infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
}
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution is ok, work for me. Didn`t thought to do that :). but anyway, why it didn`t worked at mine? i still transferred an infowindow object into the MakeConetent() function. and the creation of infowindow is worked by using that infowindow object. But not the closing.