# google maps js API v3, implement data import to multiply infowindows from database

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, spring-mvc, google-maps-api-3

The question is a little bit abstract.

My current task is to Create a google map with multiply markers and infowindows on them and to import a data from database to this infowindows.

Here is how i`m creating a map with multiply infowindows

> loadMap.js

[google maps infowindow.close() case in separate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348887/google-maps-infowindow-close-case-in-separate-function/30349102#30349102)

But now i am stuck in the question how do i import a data from DB.
I`m using intellij Idea 14 + spring MVC framework.
google maps initizalization is in the separate JS file - loadMap.js.

I can use back-end JAVA to connect to DB, but not from this JS file.
And the DB connection as i think should be in the loadMap.js, cause the markers and infowindows initialization is there.
But as i read, making of BD`s connection in JS is really bad idea cause of many reasons.

Here is the structure
http://c2n.me/3i0pxkT
loadMap.js is loaded at the maps.jsp. maps.jsp also have a controller MapsController, where i can use a back-end JAVA.

Seeking for an answer, thank you.

Comment: The data are in JSON ?

Comment: sorry, which exactly? 
for infowindows - whatever format, the problem is in algorhytm, how do i extract the data from database in the right way according to my situation.

Comment: I do not understand very well your problem. You need to import the data in the database, or you need to extract data from the database to make them available to the client so that with a javascript function you can configure the infoWindows?

Comment: i need to do both, but at first - extract the data from DB.
and thats applied to the structure reviewed above.

Comment: The DB support active record? In the abstract the easiest way to get the data consists of an action in your controller that returns a JSON file containing the data read from the database table. I believe they are available functions that convert array (or the result of the query) in JSON.
On the client side the JSON file that is made available (by a call from a GET or POST the controller/action onf the server) can be handled by a function that creates the markers on the map.
I hope this will be useful.

Comment: ye , i thought about thats. But the requests to database should be uniq for each marker. Do you think thats ok to put all the data, for example 1000 entities and use it from JSON to generate data for infowindows on the "click" action?

Comment: Using the action of clicks you could make a POST request by sending the reference of the marker which you need the information to put in the 'infowindow. In this case the controller / action on the server should invoke the appropriate query and return the JSON on the only marker concerned. In normal situations, all this happens in a few tens of milliseconds.

Comment: thats a one thing i thought about too. but thought can be other ways, cause it`s looks a bit strange. So, you think thats ok in the case of speed efficiency?

As i understood, i make it like this:
i have a map on site.com/maps.
i make a controller to handle a request like "site.com/maps?id=20"
in the controller code, i connect to DB using JAVA back-end and return a JSON answer with needed data. Am i right?

Comment: The response times in this case are not a problem. the data to be transferred are very few so bandwidth usage is practically zero. The type of query processing on the server and the client are very punctual, very little code to be executed. The flow is right, if you want another piece of advice you should use a request JQuery $ post and manage the JSON file sent from the server directly in the callback function That is executed if the request succeeds.

Comment: Ok, Yes looks like thats is the answer.
thanks for your advise! already on the way to do it.